# Do we need to submit two app to store if we wants to provide in-app feature

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex4.7

I am a new to in-app purchase and I wants to allow user to upgrade level(in-app purchase)

I am using flash builder 4.7 with 13.0 sdk.

I have searched on internet and found 1 ANE having $60, price is not an issue.

Still I eager to know do we need to submit 2 apps to app store?
1) is free and 2) is upgrade level or we need to only submit 1 application. This is more confusing because if we are going to submit only 1 application than how to pass id/name of upgrade level?

I am developing apps for iOS only

Comment: No, you don't have to, you can submit a new version for the same app with inapp feature, but make sure when you create a new version in `itunesconnect` you choose the product to added for inapp.

Comment: then how to pass its id?

Comment: If you are adding new version for same app, then your id will be same.

Comment: Ashutosh,yes that was true. But right now I wants to give app within app. 1) main free app 2) chargable level

Answer (score 1):

You will only need to submit one app to enable in-app purchase(IAP) but if it is your first IAP it will need to be submitted along with a new update to your existing app. After an app has existing IAPs available in it you can submit new ones whenever you want and not have to attach it to a version update.

Apple actually has a really nice walkthrough on how to submit IAPs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingInAppPurchases.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH5-SW1).

Comment: do you have any idea to implement through flex/flash builder 4.7?

Comment: I do not but Adobe does appear to have a tutorial on how to use StoreKit with Flash Builder 4.6 [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/storekit-ane-ios.html). Not sure if the process changed at all for version 4.7 but that should hopefully get you started.